# AngularJS - Calling function into a component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to call a function that I have into a component.

Here is the code from my component buttonsController:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

  angular
       .module('my')
       .component('myButton', {
        templateUrl: '../app/src/component/buttons.html',
        controller: buttonController,
        controllerAs: 'btnCmpnt',
        bindings: {
          newElement: '&',
          editElement: '&',
          deleteElement: '&',
          newTitle: '@',
          editTitle: '@',
          deleteTitle: '@'
        }
      });

  function buttonController($scope) {


      var vm = this;    

      vm.newElement =  () =>  {
        alert("1")
      }
      vm.editElement =  () =>  {
        alert("2")
      }
      vm.deleteElement =  () =>  {
        alert("3")
      }

  }

})();
```

Here is my buttons.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button ng-if="btnCmpnt.newTitle" title="Add configuration" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="btnCmpnt.newElement()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{btnCmpnt.newTitle}}</button>
</div>
```

And this is my html where I call my component:

```
<my-button new-title="New" new-element="newElement();"></my-button>
```

I can not do a call to my function.

Can you help me?

Regards!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you never call binding method from inside of component. Instead you overwrite it with component controller method. This

```
vm.newElement = () => {
  alert("1")
}
```

will overwrite binding:

```
newElement: '&',
```

So you have two options. You either remove `vm.newElement = () => { alert("1") }` all together.

Or other option, if you want to have wrapper in controller. You rename it and call `this.newElement()` from inside:

```
vm._newElement = () => {
  alert("1")
  this.newElement() // call binding, outside function
}
```

In this case make sure you use new function name in template:

```
ng-click="btnCmpnt._newElement()"
```

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Thank you!